# Apache POI attach file to word

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, docx

I'm interested in making Word docx with attached or embended html files int its table.

I'm able to create a .docx document with table but didn't find the ways how to add attached files to cells. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/examples/SimpleImages.java demonstrates how to add images to docx files - there are other examples too, maybe one of them can help.

Comment: Thanks, but it did bit. Looks like POI can't deal with inserting OLE Objects.

Comment: @VitoKarleone Could you able to find any solution for inserting OLE objects? I am having same problem.